# Finding the Interest Compounded with Bank Advertising Yield

Tags: interest-rates

A bank is advertising 9.5% accounts that yield 9.84% annually. How often is the interest compounded?

Answer is Quarterly.

I've been trying to look for the formula for this; it doesn't seem to be effective rate:

$$ER = (1+i)^m - 1$$

or Nominal Rate

$$i = NR/m$$

What should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quarterly compound rate:
\begin{align*}
\Big(1+\frac{0.095}{4}\Big)^4 - 1= 9.84\,\%.
\end{align*}